# /var/lib/tor is not owned by this user (root, 0) but by debian-tor (110)

Tags: configuration, relays, debian

I'm trying to set up a Tor relay on Debian Jessie. I edited the torrc file and set `RunAsDaemon 1`. When I try to start tor with `sudo tor` it returns this:

```
[warn] /var/lib/tor is not owned by this user (root, 0) but by debian-tor (110). Perhaps you are running Tor as the wrong user?
[warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Couldn't access/create private data directory "/var/lib/tor"
[err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: It seems to work now. I entered "sudo service tor restart" Screenshot: https://www2.pic-upload.de/img/33235701/Bildschirmfoto2017-05-27um11.50.01.png

Comment: You should control Tor through the `service` interface, running it directly from the command line with `sudo tor` will cause problems like those you saw, also `RunAsDaemon 1` isn't required but it's overridden by the launched service anyway (if you *did* enforce runasdaemon it would break the tor service) but you probably want to kill the instance of `tor` that's running as root: `sudo kill 5184`

Comment: 5184 is the "top" process. Was "service restart tor" the correct command? What do you mean by enforce ruasdeamon?

Comment: Basically the problem was you still had a copy of `tor` running as root, which may have interfered with the `tor` service, if it's not there anymore then this should be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of the warn message has some hints. The directory `/var/lib/tor` is owned by the user `debian-tor`. You executed `sudo tor` which means that the Tor process is run by the `root` user. This leads to the error message.

You can either execute the command as `debian-tor` user:

```
sudo -u debian-tor tor
```

or start the process via systemd (or similar means):

```
sudo systemctl start tor
sudo service tor start
```

Comment: Tor is working now. I entered this in the shell: service tor restart

Comment: N.B. that simply using `sudo -u debian-tor tor` won't provide the same functionality because it doesn't load up the torrc-defaults file to set some default settings, however it will use the settings from `/etc/tor/torrc`